# Unreliable Thunderbolt 2 startup disk

Tags: imac, startup, ssd, thunderbolt

I have attempted to improve the performance of a Mid 2011 27" iMac by booting from an external Thunderbolt SSD, specifically a Transcend 256 GB StoreJet 500. It may or may not be relevant that this does not have a separate power supply.

I have successfully installed High Sierra (10.13.2) on the drive, enabled TRIM and selected it as my startup disk in preferences, but when I first switch the computer on, it always boots from the internal hard disk. Only if I then login (which shows the external drive in Finder) and restart the computer does it boot from the external drive.

Also if I hold down ALT during the initial startup, only the internal disk is available.

I could live with this, but it's bugging me! Any idea what the issue could be, or any commands I can use to force the Mac to wait until the external drive is accessible before booting?

Comment: Have you partitioned this drive, or is it one large partition?

Comment: One large partition

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the version of macOS. Some research indicates that there may be problems with Sierra/High Sierra and booting from external drives, although I found nothing conclusive. If you had a drive with a power source, instead of bus-powered, you may have better results.  Without any proof, I would guess that power is not available to the external drive until macOS boots. Not seeing it whilst holding down the Option key at boot points to this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon - added. I did my research and reviews suggested this worked well as an external boot disk, but you may be right RE power. Frustrating because otherwise it's working well.

Comment: If you computer will only boot internally, then the solution would be to install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on your internal disk. You could configure [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to boot your external disk. The [startup manager rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) could be installed into your existing internal EFI partition or a newly created 200 MB internal JHFS+ partition.

Comment: I might also be worth mentioning, you model Mac supports adding an second internal 2.5 inch SSD. See this [website](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-faq/imac-intel-21.5-inch-27-inch-aluminum-how-to-upgrade-hard-drive.html). The new APFS format was designed optimize an internal HDD + SSD arrangement.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson - I'll check out rEFInd. Good to know about the second bay as well, though cracking the machine open was something I was hoping to avoid!

Comment: If you need help installing rEFInd, let me know. I have rEFInd installed on my Mac. I also have posted answers to other questions where rEFInd was used to boot Windows, macOS and/or Ubuntu from both internal and external drives. You can even create a USB flash drive version of rEFInd, if you want to test before installing on your internal disk.